# How to make if statement that checks if all or just one text field is empty

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtextfield

How do I make an if statement which checks if all or just one text field is empty

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    if(jTextField1.getText().equals("") && jTextField2.getText().equals("") && jTextField3.getText().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " please fill empty fields", "Input Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }else{
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me introduce you to some of the lesser known array functions: [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is listing all the Widgets with a  "or" statement:

```
 if ((attribut1.isEmpty() || attribut2.isEmpty() || attribut3.isEmpty() || attribut4.isEmpty()||attribut5.isEmpty()||attribut6.isEmpty()||attribut7.isEmpty()||attribut8.isEmpty()||attribut9.isEmpty()||attribut10.isEmpty())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "fill in all details"
```

Definitely not the nicest solution but it works.

Comment: yes i thought of this but i have no yet tried it i have also thought of using an if else statement to try and account for all possibilities of what could happen. What do you think of this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but;
If you want to check multiple properties, I would work with mutiple if () statements. Like I said it is not the nicest style of coding but it is a pretty solid solution wich is not likely to crash that fast.
If you want to check for mutiple different things you need a bunch of if statements what could be hell of work but if you have only a limited number of things you are checking i would go with that solution.

Comment: + Iam using this kind of if() statements on all my current projects and never hat a problem with it. Despite the time it takes to write them ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integer variable as a counter and if a jTextfield is empty, you can increase the counter.